# Join tables on a unique ID field, returning exactly one result row per Id value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have several tables which all have a unique ID field. I want to join them on this ID field. More precisely, I want to extract a column from each table, and line all the extracted columns with the ID value. The tables do not have entries for all ID values; I want the result to have a single row for each ID value that is present in at least one table. If an Id is missing from one of the tables, the result should have a `null`. I don't care what happens if Id values aren't unique within a table (in my data, they are).

Toy example: I have a `plant` table

```
Id  Name            Class
1   larch           pinopsida
3   horse chestnut  angiosperms
```

and an `animal` table

```
Id  Name            Cry
1   cat             meow
2   dog             bow wow
4   carp
```

and a `mineral` table

```
Id  Name            Color
2   diamond         white
3   emerald         green
```

and I want to combine them into

```
Id  Plant           Animal  Mineral
1   larch           cat     (null)
2                   dog     diamond
3   horse chestnut  (null)  emerald
4   (null)          carp    (null)
```

As far as I can tell, this isn't a straight `inner join` because that would only retain Ids present in all the databases, nor a straight `left join` or `right join` because that would only retain the Ids present in one of the tables (none of the tables contain all Id values), nor a straight `outer join` or `cross join` because those would spread Ids over multiple rows.

The database is SQL Server 2012. I'm accessing it directly, not through another programming language. The real query is https://data.stackexchange.com/cs/query/36599/show-all-types — there's got to be a better way than listing all the pairs of `Id` columns that can be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FULL JOIN`

```
Select COALESCE(p.Id, a.Id, m.Id) Id
     , MAX(p.Name) Plant
     , MAX(a.Name) Animal
     , MAX(m.Name) Mineral
FROM   Plant p
       FULL JOIN Animal a ON p.Id = a.Id
       FULL JOIN Mineral m ON p.Id = m.Id
GROUP BY COALESCE(p.Id, a.Id, m.Id)
ORDER BY COALESCE(p.Id, a.Id, m.Id)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2778a/4)</kbd>

---

If you prefer not to have `COALESCE` and `GROUP` in the query it's possible to get the Ids first and the `JOIN` the tables

```
WITH Ids AS (
  SELECT Id FROM Plant
  UNION
  SELECT Id FROM Animal
  UNION
  SELECT Id FROM Mineral
)
SELECT Ids.Id
     , p.Name Plant
     , a.Name Animal
     , m.Name Mineral
FROM   Ids
       LEFT JOIN Plant p ON Ids.Id = p.Id
       LEFT JOIN Animal a ON Ids.Id = a.Id
       LEFT JOIN Mineral m ON Ids.Id = m.Id
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2778a/6)</kbd>

Comment: @Notulysses when i posted it your was not on the page, probably because of all those delete/undelete...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE(t.id, a.id, m.id) AS [ID]
     , MAX(t.name) AS Plant     
     , MAX(a.name) AS Animal
     , MAX(m.name) AS Mineral
FROM plant t FULL OUTER JOIN mineral m ON m.id = t.id
             FULL OUTER JOIN animal a ON a.id = t.id
GROUP BY COALESCE(t.id, a.id, m.id)
ORDER BY [ID]
```

[**Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92c92/17)

Comment: I stumbled upon that a few minutes after asking… Is that the “right way” to do it? It seems strange to build rows and then collapse them together, and to repeat the `coalesce` statement, but then I learnt all my SQL by fumbling in the dark, so what do I know.

Comment: @Gilles : Well, I am a bit frustrated with using `MAX` (and any other aggregate function seems to be kludge to me too).

Comment: This query does not allow for the case where animal and mineral have the same id while plant has a gap at that position.

Comment: @shawnt00 : Yes it does, check example for `id` = 2. That is why, actually, I use `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN animal a ON a.id = t.id will not match when t.id is null as will happen with id equal to 2.

Comment: @shawnt00 : It will and you can see it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e8142/2). The thing is that in that case there will be 2 rows with `id` = 2 before the group by and aggregation. After that this two rows will be merged and null values in different fields from both rows will be replaced with actual string values.

Comment: Sorry, I was overlooking the aggregation. You are correct and I've used that approach too.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could also have an anchoring table:

```
select anchor.Id, A.name, B.Name, C.Name
from
    (
        select distinct Id
        from (select Id from A union all select Id from B union all select Id from C) as T
    ) as anchor
    left outer join A on A.Id = anchor.Id
    left outer join B on B.Id = anchor.Id
    left outer join C on C.Id = anchor.Id
```

I had forgotten to made the ids distinct in the anchor table but that's very important.

Comment: I wasn't trying to steal your answer. Geez, my first answer satisfied the question and I only added this because of the down vote. I've been doing this for twenty years and I've got better things to do than worry about this crap.

Comment: I had forgotten to made the ids distinct in the anchor table but that's very important. And since I rarely use UNION (instead of UNION ALL) I forgot that it would easily eliminate the duplicate ids in the anchor table. This answer is clearly equivalent to Serpiton's.

Answer (score -1):

```
select coalesce(A.Id, B.Id, C.Id) as Id, ...
from
    A
    full outer join B on B.Id = A.Id
    full outer join C on C.Id = A.Id or C.Id = B.Id
```

The key is in the ORed join condition. It could also be written as C.Id = coalesce(A.Id, B.Id)

The groupings used in other answers aren't necessary if your id values are primary keys in the individual tables.

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I want to avoid listing all the pairs of Ids that can be equal. With 3 tables it's manageable, but with 8 and potentially growing, it isn't.

Comment: The coalesce eliminates much of the duplication but I can't change reality for you.

Comment: This is really not a convention thing to do with a well-designed database and that's why there isn't a straightforward approach. As you seemed to be unaware of full outer joins I took that statement as a hint at what was going on in your thought processes while trying to solve it using only the other kinds of joins. You failed to mention anything about using this approach will a growing number of tables and I'd say that downvoting a working answer is pretty unfair.